# jPlayer - Implementing Rewind Functionality via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, keypress, jplayer

I've run into an issue using **[jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/)** and I thought after searching a few places that it would be used commonly enough on here and someone is bound to have run into a similar issue.

I am using the jPlayer to play through audio files and my users would like the functionality to fast-forward and rewind via specific hotkeys. I noticed that jPlayer doesn't offer this functionality out of the box (*it only handles fast-forward and rewind through clicking on the progress bar currently*)

Ideally - all that would be necessary would be for a single keypress to toggle the fast-forwarding (or rewinding). When the same key is pressed again, the audio file would begin playing based on the current location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to implement my own solution to this, which currently seems to work just fine. I thought I would share it in case anyone else encounters such an issue.

Pardon the crude implementation. It was just a proof of concept:

**Necessary Javascript:**

```
//Handles the key down event (so the user can hold a key down to continue)
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    //Rewind
    if (e.keyCode == 37 && (!rewinding)) {
        rewinding = true;
        //Pause the player
        $("#player").jPlayer("pause");
        RewindTrack();
        rwaction = window.setInterval(function () { RewindTrack() }, 500);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39 && (!fastforward)) {
        fastforward = true;
        //Pause the player
        $("#player").jPlayer("pause");
        FastforwardTrack();
        ffaction = window.setInterval(function () { FastforwardTrack() }, 500);
    }
});
//Ends the action
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    //Rewind
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        rewinding = false;
        window.clearInterval(rwaction);
        $("#player").jPlayer("pause");
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        fastforward = false;
        window.clearInterval(ffaction);
        $("#player").jPlayer("pause");
    }
});

//Related function
function GetPlayerProgress() {
    return ($('.jp-play-bar').width() / $('.jp-seek-bar').width() * 100);
}

//Handles rewinding
function RewindTrack() {
    //Get current progress and decrement
    var currentProgress = GetPlayerProgress();
    //Rewinds 10% of track length
    var futureProgress = currentProgress - 10;
    //If it goes past the starting point - stop rewinding and pause
    if (futureProgress <= 0) {
        rewinding = false;
        window.clearInterval(rwaction);
        $("#player").jPlayer("pause", 0);
    }
    //Continue rewinding
    else {
        $("#player").jPlayer("playHead", parseInt(futureProgress, 10));
    }
}

//Fast forwards the track
function FastforwardTrack() {
    //Get current progress and increment
    var currentProgress = GetPlayerProgress();
    //Fast forwards 10%
    var futureProgress = currentProgress + 10;
    //If the percentage exceeds the max - stop fast forwarding at the end.
    if (futureProgress >= 100) {
        fastforward = false;
        window.clearInterval(ffaction);
        $("#player").jPlayer("playHead", parseInt($('.jp-duration').text().replace(':', '')));
    }
    else {
        $("#player").jPlayer("playHead", parseInt(futureProgress, 10));
    }
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FMZfF/)** (Use left arrow for rewind and right for fast-forward)

Comment: $("#player").jPlayer("pause", 0);
This is not working on ipad/iphone. can you help me out?